# How do i seach an sql column for data that already exists from python?

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite, authentication

New to python and even newer to sql and i'm simply trying to check sql for usernames that already exists for a log in program but can't quite figure it out. Here's my code:

```
def validuser():
cursor.execute("SELECT username FROM OCRflix EXISTS")
if cursor.execute == 0:
    print("That username already exists")
else:
    print("secure password")
```

I'm aware of sql injection but this is just practise and wont be used, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sql = 'select exists(select 1 from OCRflix where username = ? limit 1)'
cursor.execute(sql, (myUsername,));

if cursor.fetchone()[0] == 1:
    # username found
    pass
else:
    # username not found
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
sql = "SELECT username FROM OCRflix WHERE username=?"
result = cursor.execute(sql, (user_input,)

if result:
   print("Username already exits")
else:
   print("secure Password")
```

the above program checks if the user input is already present in the username column.